# Removing or sealing dryer hose in wall

Tags: bathroom, repair, dryer

We recently purchased a ventless compact washer/dryer set for our bathroom. We no longer need the previous dryer hose and would love to seal it off or remove it. I figured that we'd seal it in case someone later wants to install a vented dryer (though the bathroom is so small that I don't know if that will ever be the case).

The problem we're having is that the top and bottom parts of the hose stick out from the wall/ceiling inextremely unattractive ways. The previous owners built a wooden "box" around the hose to (not really) hide it. At the top, it's foam sealed into the ceiling.

I don't want to go hacking away at it with a Sawzall unless there's no other option to remove it. I don't want to make it more difficult for anyone in the future but I also don't want to leave it as it is, especially unsealed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can get oval ducting that's designed to fit in a 2x4 wall. That would require replacing all of this which would require cutting the wall open to get this stuff out, possibly opening the ceiling to reroute there, then covering it all back up. Excellent opportunity to upgrade your drywall skills if you're interested in doing so.

Comment: Interesting that they used double-wall "B-vent" for that. Any chance there's another device attached?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You have two obvious options--detach at the next joints or hack it up. Take your pick and good luck to you.

Comment: @isherwood oh God I hope there's not anything else connected. I dont think there is, anything else requiring duct work is on the other side of the house. Otherwise, I feel like you're giving me permission to cut away the hose lol.

Comment: @FreeMan that sounds like something I should leave to someone who wants a vented dryer lol! My drywall skills are very limited so I imagine that I'd just make a mess. Thank you though.

Comment: I would mostly be concerned with closing up the termination properly, but you haven't shown or asked us about that. What you do with the interior duct is mostly an aesthetic and practical decision.

Comment: IMO the easiest solution would be to throw a cap on the stub at the bottom, and build a small chase for the bit at the ceiling.